# issues connecting with the firebase database (app keeps crashing whenever i attempt to save to the database)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so i am making a diary application where users log in and then start writing on a diary app that anyone who has the application can access , the application was working fine but after integrating a second layout (the login layout) and the firebase authentication, the application crashes whenever i try to save or view anything from the database. moreover nothing seems to be saved in the database

the second issue is that i would like the userId under which the notes will be saved to be the email the user entered when signing up not the key that firebase can generate

I have tried checking both build gradles and they seem to be working just fine, i also tried just setting the user ID to be 123 to make sure it isn't null
i also tried different versions of android to test it but nothing seems to be working

```
 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
 DatabaseReference mDatabase = database.getReference("diary");






 saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            String diaryTitle =  titleText.getText().toString();
            String diaryContent = diaryText.getText().toString();
            if(diaryTitle.length()==0||diaryContent.length()==0)

            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication().getBaseContext(), "FIELD(S) CANNOT BE EMPTY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else {
                String userId = "123";
                diaryclass userDiary = new diaryclass(diaryTitle, diaryContent);
                mDatabase.child(userId).setValue(userDiary);
                titleText.setText("");
                diaryText.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(getApplication().getBaseContext(), "text saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }
    });
```

and below the the class that has the diaryclass constructor

```
public class diaryclass extends diary{

public  String Title;
public  String Diary;

public  diaryclass(){

}

public  diaryclass(String Title,String Diary){
    this.Title=Title;
    this.Diary=Diary;
}
}
```

this is what the data base looked like before when it worked
[image: the firebase view of the data saved]

please feel free to ask any questions as i would appreciate any kind of help
below is a link to the entire project if that would help
[click here for the android studio project in zip format](https://studentsaduac-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/heithem_hafsi_adu_ac_ae/EeRo9eNH7khEh2CJtqdfVAkBO9JxIi2kxdX-2aj-TXeY5Q?e=c56agr)

for those intrested in the entire code

```
package ir.mhkz.loginandsignup;

   import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
   import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.EditText;

     import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
       import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

       public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


EditText password, reg_password,
         reg_email, reg_confirmemail;
Button login, signUp, reg_register;
TextInputLayout txtInLayoutUsername, txtInLayoutPassword, txtInLayoutRegPassword;
CheckBox rememberMe;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    reg_email = findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = findViewById(R.id.password);
    login = findViewById(R.id.login);
    signUp = findViewById(R.id.signUp);
    txtInLayoutUsername = findViewById(R.id.txtInLayoutUsername);
    txtInLayoutPassword = findViewById(R.id.txtInLayoutPassword);
    rememberMe = findViewById(R.id.rememberMe);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    ClickLogin();


    //SignUp's Button for showing registration page
    signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ClickSignUp();
        }
    });


}

//This is method for doing operation of check login
private void ClickLogin() {

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (reg_email.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {

                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Please fill out these fields",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
                snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                snackbar.show();
                txtInLayoutUsername.setError("Username should not be empty");
            } else {
                //Here you can write the codes for checking username
            }
            if (password.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Please fill out these fields",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
                snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                snackbar.show();
                txtInLayoutPassword.setError("Password should not be empty");
            } else {
                //Here you can write the codes for checking password
            }

            if (rememberMe.isChecked()) {
                //Here you can write the codes if box is checked
            } else {
                //Here you can write the codes if box is not checked
            }

            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(reg_email.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString());

        }

    });

}

//The method for opening the registration page and another processes or checks for registering
private void ClickSignUp() {
    final Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(this,diary.class);


    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.register, null);
    dialog.setView(dialogView);

    reg_password = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
    reg_email = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
    reg_confirmemail = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.reg_confirmemail);
    reg_register = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.reg_register);
    txtInLayoutRegPassword = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txtInLayoutRegPassword);

    reg_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (reg_password.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                txtInLayoutRegPassword.setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled(false);
                reg_password.setError("Please fill out this field");
            } else {
                txtInLayoutRegPassword.setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled(true);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            if (reg_email.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {

                reg_email.setError("Please fill out this field");
            } else {
                //Here you can write the codes for checking email
            }
            if (reg_confirmemail.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {

                reg_confirmemail.setError("Please fill out this field");
            } else {
                //Here you can write the codes for checking confirmemail
            }
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(reg_email.getText().toString(),reg_password.getText().toString());

        }
    });
    dialog.show();
   }


    }
```

and this is the part that the user uses to save and view the diary

```
package ir.mhkz.loginandsignup;

 import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
      import android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.Snapshot;
     import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
  import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
  import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
  import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
  import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
  import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
  import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
  import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
  import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;

  public class diary extends MainActivity {
EditText titleText;
EditText diaryText;
Button saveBtn;
Button viewdata;
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference mDatabase = database.getReference().child("diary");
TextView dtitle;
TextView ddiary;
Button clear;
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.diary_layout);
    titleText=findViewById(R.id.editTextTitle);
    diaryText=findViewById(R.id.editTextDiary);
    saveBtn = findViewById(R.id.buttonSaveDiary);
    viewdata= findViewById(R.id.viewbutton);
    dtitle = findViewById(R.id.displaytitle);
    ddiary = findViewById(R.id.displaydiary);
    clear = findViewById(R.id.buttoncln);
    dtitle.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    ddiary.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    final FirebaseAuth mAuth = null;
    final String userId;
    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    }

    viewdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dtitle.setText("");
            ddiary.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(getApplication().getBaseContext(), "text updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    List<diaryclass> DiaryList = new ArrayList<diaryclass>();
                    dtitle.setText("");
                    ddiary.setText("");

                    for (DataSnapshot diarySnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        diaryclass thediary = diarySnapshot.getValue(diaryclass.class);
                        DiaryList.add(thediary);
                    }
                    for (int i=0 ; i<DiaryList.size();i++) {
                        diaryclass listofstuff = DiaryList.get(i);
                        String titlelist=listofstuff.Title;
                        String diarylist = listofstuff.Diary;
                        dtitle.append(i+ "\n" ) ;
                        dtitle.append(titlelist + "\n" ) ;
                        dtitle.append("\n" ) ;
                        dtitle.append("\n" ) ;
                        dtitle.append(diarylist + "\n" ) ;
                        dtitle.append("\n" ) ;

                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }

            });

        }

    });
    saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            String diaryTitle = titleText.getText().toString();
            String diaryContent = diaryText.getText().toString();
            if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                mDatabase.child(userId).setValue(diaryTitle, diaryContent)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplication().getBaseContext(), "Saved...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    titleText.setText("");
                                    diaryText.setText("");
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }

            clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    titleText.setText("");
                    diaryText.setText("");
                    dtitle.setText("");
                    ddiary.setText("");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication().getBaseContext(), "text cleared ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            });


        }
    });
}
}
```

and the gradle is working just fine so i dont think it is needed and the other class is already available up there

logcat below

> 2019-04-15 04:00:01.684 1778-1803/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
>
> 2019-04-15 04:00:57.777 1869-1869/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
>
> 2019-04-15 04:00:57.777 1869-1869/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
>
> 2019-04-15 04:01:00.007 1926-1940/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
>
> 2019-04-15 04:01:00.032 1926-1940/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
>
> 2019-04-15 04:01:00.049 1926-1940/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
>
> 2019-04-15 04:01:01.687 1778-1803/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: If the application crashes, find the error message and stack trace in the logcat output and add them to your question please.

Comment: here is the logcat

Comment: ill add it to the question

Comment: wow - that's a lot of code. Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also It’s a good idea to include code and structures as text, not links and images. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: @Jay The code i included at the bottom is if someone wants the entire code but in the beginning i include the bits of code that are necessary and the picture was not of code ,it was how the data was saved in the firebase database

Comment: Understood. We really don't need to see the entire code, as mentioned in the link in my comment, just the applicable parts that will duplicate the issue. We often like to use Firebase data in answers and if it's a picture, we have to retype it which makes us grumpy. That's why I also mentioned *and structures* and then demonstrated how tot get it. Shortening the code and adhering to the guides will help us to help you!

Answer (score 1):

I did not download your complete code but try to save data on firebase like this
First change `DatabaseReference mDatabase = database.getReference("diary");` if diary is the direct child of your database to `DatabaseReference mDatabase = database.getReference().child("diary");` 
2nd you have to get the id of the current user for that

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
String userId;
if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
   userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
}
```

3rd to save data on `Firebase DataBase` make sure current user is loged in

```
if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
    mDatabase.child(userId).setValue(userDiary)
               .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                  if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Saved...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     titleText.setText("");
                     diaryText.setText("");
                  }
               });
   }
```

4th be sure in your `diaryclass` make `GETTER` and `SETTER` for all your variabels.

Comment: so i tried that now it is not compiling, i will add the rest of the code in the question

Comment: Your `diaryclass` extends `diary` basicaly your `diaryclass` is a model class in case of firebase database you do not have to extend it. As i have mentioned earler make `getter` and `setter` for your variables. In your case you did not have to extend class `diary` with your `MainActivity`, but it will do work.  Make flow chart first and name your activities PROPERLY. Use camel case formate for your variables. And try to learn from tutorials on youtube or any other source you are not doing it a right way. May be i will write working code for you but it will not help you because to need to learn

Comment: Sorry for straight forward answer. If you did not find any solution you can wright me i will guide you to do in a right way.

Comment: no it is really fine man i am just confused when it comes to so many bits of code connecting and im trying to learn from you tube and all any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please repeat your tutorial. First follow the full tutorial then make project for your need i think you will better under stand this way. Do not see too many tutorials first choose which person you can understand better then follow his tutorial. I have already helped you but you can not understand that's why i say you to follow tutorials. Your problem is not the code but understanding of code. And in your `diary` class you have initialised `FirebaseAuth` as `null` it will alway be `null`. Initialise it as you did it in your `MainActivity` class.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but symbols like @ cannot be use as a name for a firebase database path that's why they generate unique key.